# JanusGraph - slow retrieval of vertices by ID

Tags: java, cassandra, gremlin, janusgraph

Currently I am working on a project that uses JanusGraph (version 0.2.0) with Apache Cassandra (version 2.1.19) as its data storage backend. This project is writen in Java and uses TinkerPop3 Gremlin and its Java API to connect to Janus.

Goal of this project is to insert graph structure from CVS files containing approximately 8 milion entities (nodes, edges and attributes).

Import of nodes is quite fast. Problem occurs, when I want to retrieve node with certain ID via `internalGraph.vertices(id).next();` Each retrieval takes nearly uniformly 15ms (13-16).

To offset this, I addded `"storage.batch-loading", "true"` to configuration of the Graph which seems to help, but only if there are no more queries (checking for certain type of duplicates in the graph). When i add simple graph query to the mix, such as

```
Iterator<Vertex> vertexIterator = db.getTraversal().V(nodeAttr.id())
                      .inE().hasLabel(MainConfig.EDGE_ATTRIBUTE_LABEL).outV();
```

the retrieval time goes back up to 15ms.

Does anyone know what the problem could be? I would be grateful for any tips or hints. Thank you.

Comment: I recommend you luck at the following blog posts:
- http://www.scylladb.com/2017/12/21/performance-evaluation-scylla-4-janusgraph/

Comment: Can't edit after 5 min... here is what I intended to write:

Engineers from IBM compared Cassandra, HBase and Scylla as data storage backend for JanusGraph , here are their findings: http://www.scylladb.com/2017/12/21/performance-evaluation-scylla-4-janusgraph/

Comment: can you update your question to describe the deployment configuration? is your client program running on the same machine as JanusGraph and Cassandra?